# Android Studio 3.0 and app freezing

Tags: android, crash, freeze, android-studio-3.0

I've updated my **android studio from 2.x** to **android 3.0 stable**.

Since then when I try to push an application to my **Nexus 7** 2012 with cyanogenmod 12.1 (android 5.1.1) the entire system freeze and crash.

At the reboot the system show the launcher but it's all friezed until I uninstall the app.
I've tried with different apps, also release compiled, and different Nexus 7 (same hardware and software), exactly same results.

With different devices I have no problems.
What's going on? Thank you.

```
11-06 13:56:05.681 2304-2304/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
11-06 13:56:05.681 2304-2304/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
11-06 13:56:05.737 2304-2304/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
11-06 13:56:06.057 489-525/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc 2317:com.android.defcontainer/u0a6 for service com.android.defcontainer/.DefaultContainerService
11-06 13:56:06.080 2317-2327/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
11-06 13:56:06.132 489-525/system_process D/PackageManager: /data/app/vmdl835727952.tmp already staged; skipping copy
11-06 13:56:06.416 489-525/system_process D/PackageManager: Renaming /data/app/vmdl835727952.tmp to /data/app/com.unipiazza.fismunipiazza-1
11-06 13:56:06.463 489-525/system_process I/PackageManager: Running dexopt on: /data/app/com.unipiazza.fismunipiazza-1/base.apk pkg=com.unipiazza.fismunipiazza isa=arm vmSafeMode=false
11-06 13:56:06.487 2345-2345/? I/dex2oat: /system/bin/dex2oat --zip-fd=6 --zip-location=/data/app/com.unipiazza.fismunipiazza-1/base.apk --oat-fd=7 --oat-location=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.unipiazza.fismunipiazza-1@base.apk@classes.dex --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=default --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --swap-fd=8
11-06 13:56:06.525 489-504/system_process I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 101584(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 57(1225KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 12MB/19MB, paused 2.001ms total 105.069ms
11-06 13:56:06.538 2345-2345/? I/dex2oat: Decided to run without swap.
11-06 13:56:06.629 2345-2345/? I/dex2oat: dex2oat took 141.194ms (threads: 4) arena alloc=104KB java alloc=48KB native alloc=1371KB free=28KB
11-06 13:56:06.737 489-525/system_process V/BackupManagerService: restoreAtInstall pkg=com.unipiazza.fismunipiazza token=1 restoreSet=0
11-06 13:56:06.737 489-525/system_process V/BackupManagerService: Finishing install immediately
11-06 13:56:06.741 489-525/system_process W/Settings: Setting install_non_market_apps has moved from android.provider.Settings.Global to android.provider.Settings.Secure, returning read-only value.

                                                      --------- beginning of crash
11-06 13:56:06.749 1061-1127/com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet A/libc: invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xaee9 passed to dlfree
11-06 13:56:06.750 1061-1127/com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 1127 (launcher-loader)
11-06 13:56:06.750 138-138/? I/DEBUG: property debug.db.uid not set; NOT waiting for gdb.
11-06 13:56:06.750 138-138/? I/DEBUG: HINT: adb shell setprop debug.db.uid 100000
11-06 13:56:06.750 138-138/? I/DEBUG: HINT: adb forward tcp:5039 tcp:5039
11-06 13:56:06.752 489-573/system_process I/InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000020
11-06 13:56:06.756 489-489/system_process D/BackupManagerService: Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.unipiazza.fismunipiazza flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }
11-06 13:56:06.768 489-489/system_process W/BackupManagerService: Removing schedule queue dupe of com.unipiazza.fismunipiazza
11-06 13:56:06.790 489-511/system_process W/Searchables: No global search activity found
11-06 13:56:06.810 138-138/? I/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
11-06 13:56:06.810 138-138/? I/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/nakasi/grouper:5.1/LMY47D/1743759:user/release-keys'
11-06 13:56:06.810 138-138/? I/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
11-06 13:56:06.810 138-138/? I/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
11-06 13:56:06.810 489-651/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc 2351:org.cyanogenmod.themes.provider/u0a15 for broadcast org.cyanogenmod.themes.provider/.AppReceiver
11-06 13:56:06.811 138-138/? I/DEBUG: pid: 1061, tid: 1127, name: launcher-loader  >>> com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet <<<
11-06 13:56:06.812 138-138/? I/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xdeadbaad
11-06 13:56:06.798 138-138/? W/debuggerd: type=1400 audit(0.0:218): avc: denied { write } for name="ndebugsocket" dev=mmcblk0p9 ino=1730173 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:system_ndebug_socket:s0 tclass=fifo_file
11-06 13:56:06.832 657-657/com.android.nfc A/libc: invalid address or address of corrupt block 0x8d09 passed to dlfree
11-06 13:56:06.832 657-657/com.android.nfc A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 657 (com.android.nfc)
11-06 13:56:06.858 138-138/? I/DEBUG: Abort message: 'invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xaee9 passed to dlfree'
11-06 13:56:06.858 138-138/? I/DEBUG:     r0 00000000  r1 401fbdec  r2 deadbaad  r3 00000000
11-06 13:56:06.858 138-138/? I/DEBUG:     r4 0000aee9  r5 401fd0d8  r6 4000a000  r7 0000aef1
11-06 13:56:06.859 138-138/? I/DEBUG:     r8 6c1ee42c  r9 6c1ee4ec  sl 40222236  fp 4022223f
11-06 13:56:06.859 138-138/? I/DEBUG:     ip 00000000  sp 6c1ee3d8  lr 401cd20b  pc 401cd20c  cpsr 600e0030
11-06 13:56:06.859 138-138/? I/DEBUG: backtrace:
11-06 13:56:06.859 138-138/? I/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0002920c  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+1239)
11-06 13:56:06.859 138-138/? I/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0000f363  /system/lib/libc.so (free+10)
11-06 13:56:06.859 138-138/? I/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00012b07  /system/lib/libandroidfw.so (android::ResStringPool::uninit()+38)
11-06 13:56:06.859 138-138/? I/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00013843  /system/lib/libandroidfw.so (android::ResXMLTree::uninit()+12)
11-06 13:56:06.859 138-138/? I/DEBUG:     #04 pc 00013861  /system/lib/libandroidfw.so (android::ResXMLTree::~ResXMLTree()+4)
11-06 13:56:06.859 138-138/? I/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00010527  /system/lib/libandroidfw.so (android::AssetManager::getPkgName(char const*)+258)
11-06 13:56:06.859 138-138/? I/DEBUG:     #06 pc 00010589  /system/lib/libandroidfw.so (android::AssetManager::getBasePackageName(unsigned int)+68)
11-06 13:56:06.859 138-138/? I/DEBUG:     #07 pc 00082007  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
11-06 13:56:06.859 138-138/? I/DEBUG:     #08 pc 0027b473  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat
11-06 13:56:06.873 2351-2351/? A/libc: invalid address or address of corrupt block 0x451 passed to dlfree
11-06 13:56:06.874 2351-2351/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 2351 (themes.provider)
11-06 13:56:06.891 489-525/system_process I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 16254(1113KB) AllocSpace objects, 5(80KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 12MB/18MB, paused 1.753ms total 147.497ms
11-06 13:56:06.896 2304-2304/? I/art: System.exit called, status: 0
11-06 13:56:06.896 2304-2304/? I/AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 0.
11-06 13:56:07.256 2375-2375/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
11-06 13:56:07.260 2375-2375/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is OFF
```

Comment: I'm gonna say something obvious, but have you tried to clean and rebuild your project?

Comment: Yes, by the way with the same conditions other devices has no problems

Comment: Some of my users have the same problem but I cannot test it with a device. Does changing the buildToolsVersion in gradle make a difference?

Comment: buildToolsVersion must be 26.0.2 for gradle 3.0.0....I don't know which version to test
I've tried also the android studio canary version, no changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had the same issue after updating to version 3.

solved this by installing Android SDK Buildtools version 27.0.1 and change 
the buildToolsVersion to '27.0.1' in my build.gradle

Comment: I have this problem too (Android Studio 3.0 repeatedly freezes up on me).  I just tried updating my buildToolsVersion to 27.0.1, but it didn't fix the freezing problem for me.  I've noticed that it freezes very often when I'm navigating through code via key shortcuts.  Particularly, if I jump into anything that requires a jar to be decompiled, Android Studio 3.0 almost always freezes on me.  I'm using this on a Mac.

Comment: Thank you malled , solved!

@metaphyze here we are talking about app freezing on the device while lunching...not about android studio freezing

Comment: @metaphyze did you find a solution to your problem? Mine keeps freezing as well :(

Comment: Android Studio 3.0 is still freezing on me.  However, Android Studio 3.1 Canary 5 is working.  It seems to be related to preview rendering of layouts.  I opened an issue with Google here:  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69218575 . Android Studio 3.1 Canary 3 was still freezing.  They seemed to have fixed it in Canary 5.

Comment: My Android studio version is 3.2.1 and the app keeps freezing.